# Definition $2\pi$ periodic functions

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function defined as
$$
f=|x|=\begin{cases}
-x&x\in[-\pi,0[\\
x&x\in[0,\pi[
\end{cases}
$$

> What is $g(x)=f(2x)$ and $h(x)=f(x)+\frac{f(2x)}{2}$?

Using the definition of $f$ I get that 
$$
\begin{split}
g(x)&=|2x|=\begin{cases}
-2x&x\in[-\pi,0[\\
2x&x\in[0,\pi[
\end{cases}
\\
h(x)&=
|x|+\frac{g(x)}{2}=
\begin{cases}
-x-x&x\in[-\pi,0[\\
x+x&x\in[0,\pi[
\end{cases}
=
g(x)
\end{split}
$$
I'm quite sure this is wrong - can anyone help em out?

Comment: Why don't you make a plot of the functions and see whether what you obtained is correct or not?

Comment: if $x\in[0,\pi[$ then $2x\in[0,2\pi[$. Do you see the problem with your approach?

Comment: Yes, since that would make $f(2x)=-x$ for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi[$.

Comment: But how do I take into account for that? I can't wrap my head around it.